# How do I keep the little icons in the input box?

Tags: html, css

Here is my CSS code:

```
.form-input::before{
    content: "\f2c0";
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 1.9%;
    padding-left: 0.3%;
}
.form-input:nth-child(2)::before{
    content: "\f023";
    padding-left: 0.4%;
}
```

Here is the code in my jsp file, which is written in html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action=<%=request.getContextPath() + "/Login"%> method="POST">
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="Enter Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter Password">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-login">
    </form>
    <a href=<%=request.getContextPath() + "/join.jsp"%>>Sign up now</a>
</div>
```

The current is effect is like this:[image]
However, when I resize my window, the icons go off like this:[image]

Comment: Does `.form-input` have `position: relative`?

Comment: Have you tried putting the font icon unicode inside the input placeholder like this? <input type="text" placeholder="&#xf2bd;" />

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to have an icon div as a sibling of each input and use position: absolute and use `top` & `left` to position them.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action=<%=request.getContextPath() + "/Login"%> method="POST">
        <div class="form-input">
            <div class="icon_1></div>
            <input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="Enter Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-input">
            <div class="icon_2></div>
            <input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Enter Password">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-login">
    </form>
    <a href=<%=request.getContextPath() + "/join.jsp"%>>Sign up now</a>
</div>
```

Then make sure the form-input class is set to `position: absolute`.
Set `position: absolute` on both icon_1 and icon_2 and position them with `top` and `left`.